# How to increase header size limit Tomcat Java

Tags: java, http, tomcat, header

Looking at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html I see that 8KB is the default limit of Header Size in Tomcat Apache.

The log shows the following when I make a request with headers more than the default 8KB:

`Dec 30, 2019 1:59:26 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor service
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:720)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeader(Http11InputBuffer.java:867)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:563)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:311)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

My Java Project does not have a `server.xml` inside `/webapp/WEB-INF`, just the `web.xml`. I tried to create a `server.xml` and add the following like said in this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/56691/whats-the-maximum-url-length-in-tomcat):

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" maxPostSize="4194304"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>//webapp/WEB-INF`

How Can I increase the default size limit? I'd like to set 16KB.

Thanks in advance =)

PS: I am new in Tomcat/Java World, so sorry if I made a horrible mistake =p

Comment: The `server.xml` to be edit is in the dir `config` of your server, not in a direcotry of your source code

Comment: @Renato I'm using Tomcat Embbeded, is that change the way to configure?

Comment: https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/spring-boot-app-rejects-http-request-with-total-header-size-larger-than-8kb

Comment: @AndrewG I'm not using Spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [API doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/overview-summary.html) seems that this one

```
Tomcat t = new Tomcat();
t.getConnector().setAttribute("maxHttpHeaderSize",65536);
```

could be a valid solution.

Comment: That worked. It was not clear to be that the method setAttribute is used to set the methods in the link http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html =D Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Edit Tomcat's `server.xml` and add `maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Connector 
        port="8080" 
        protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
        maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" 
        maxPostSize="4194304"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```